# Transformation with High Pass Filter

Tags: matlab, fft, matlab-guide

I Read the image `'abc.jpg'` im MATLAB and covert its data type to double.Display the image.
Store the size of image in M and N. All the loops of x, y, u and v runs till image size.
[image]

**Now I want to know 
1:how Multiply the above input image by `(-1)^x+y` To Center the Transform To `U = M/2 And V = N/2`.**

**2:multiply it with `ideal HPF(High Pass Filter) with value of D=50.`** where D is the radius size of Ideal HPF.

After Multiplying with Ideal HPF the resulting image will look like this.
[image]

Comment: we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am not here to do my home work on you.. It is the problem i am facing.. and stackoverflow is the forum so that we can discuss and share our problems here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> n1=rgb2gray(imread('fin.jpg'));
> imshow(n1);
>
> F=fft2(double(n1));
> ```
>
> %Calculate Size of Image
>
> ```
> [M,N]=size(F);
> ```
>
> %Distance Radius Size
>
> ```
> D0=50;
> n=2;
> u=0:(M-1);
> v=0:(N-1);
> idx=find(u>M/2);
> u(idx)=u(idx)-M;
> idy=find(v>N/2);
> v(idy)=v(idy)-N;
> [V,U]=meshgrid(v,u);
> ```

%Distance Calculation for High Pass Filter using Distance Formula

> ```
> D=sqrt(U.^2+V.^2);
>
> H=double(D>D0);
> subplot(2,1,1);
> imshow(fftshift(H));
> G=H.*F;
> g=real(ifft2(double(G)));
> [a,b]=size(g);
> for x=1:a
>     for y=1:b
>         sharpen_image(x,y)=(g(x,y))*(-1)^((x)+(y));
>     end
> end
> figure
> imshow(sharpen_image);
> ```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An ideal HPF is a 0-1 filter that reduce to zero all frequencies lower than `D`.

```
>> sz = size( a ); % size of image, assuming image is gray-level and not color
>> [u v] = meshgrid( .5 * linspace( -sz(1), sz(1), sz(1) ),...
                     .5 * linspace( -sz(2), sz(2), sz(2) ) ); % construct the grid for the freq domain
>> hpf = ifftshift( sqrt( u.^2 + v.^2 ) <= D ); % construct the filter
>> A = fft2( a ); 
>> fA = A.*hpf; % apply the filter in freq domain
>> fa = abs( ifft2( fA ) ); % back to image domain
```

Comment: An ideal HPF is a 0-1 filter that blocks off the lower frequencies which are below the cutoff frequency D

Answer (score 3):

Since you placed a bounty, I wrote an enhanced reply.

I should mention that you might want to consider using an appropriate window filter before calculating your fft to avoid border artifacts (I included this option in the code below). I hope it helps.

Here is a suggestion for your code:

```
a=rgb2gray(imread('abc.jpg'))
D=50;
[x y i]=size(a);
```

Generating a Hanning window to suppress border artifacts: (optional)

```
hannx = hann(x); hanny = hann(y);
Hann = hannx * hanny';
```

Calculating the 2D fft of the weighted image: (remove .*Hann if you don't want it)

```
FreqDomain=fftshift(fft2(a.*Hann));
```

Generating a disc-shaped binary mask with radius D:

```
Mask = fspecial('disk',D)==0;
Mask = imresize(padarray(Mask, [floor((x/2)-D) floor((y/2)-D)], 1, 'both'), [x y]);
```

Masking the frequency domain image:

```
MaskedFFT=FreqDomain.*Mask;
```

Computing inverse FFT:

```
Filtereda=ifft2(MaskedFFT, 'symmetric');
```

Note that the code assumes `D` is smaller than `x/2` and `y/2`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do, but it seems like you're trying to implement a high pass filter based on a FFT.

That is how I would proceed:

```
a=imread('abc.jpg')
FreqDomain=fftshift(fft(a));
```

(`fftshift` is centering the 0 frequency component)

And then crop `FreqDomain` to whichever cutoff you like, and apply `ifft` to the cropped image.

Comment: Where is the value of D in the above ans ??

Comment: I did not understand what is D.I guess it has something to do with the cutoff frequency, but can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: yes it is cut off frequency...

Comment: So, the first thing you need to do is dimension D, and understand spatial frequency. I would suggest reading this post: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13896#answer_19151 Then you can design a binary mask (an image with ones and zeroes) with a circle shape in the middle. Set the radius of the circle to D and multiply your fft with the mask. Then ifft to get the filtered image.