# Matlab: Setting complex-number array values is slow

Tags: arrays, matlab, complex-numbers

I'm a Matlab Newb. I'm currently experimenting with Fourier Transformation and trying to implement a frequency filter (deleting all frequencies but those between k_min and k_max).

In order to realize that, I'm deleting the respective pixels in the Fourier transformed image. I'm using the following code:

```
% Example values
kmin = 0;
kmax = 300;

for i = 1:w
    for j = 1:h
        if norm([w/2, h/2] - [i,j]) < kmin || norm([w/2, h/2] - [i,j]) > kmax
            Fs(j,i) = 0.0;
        end
    end
end
```

My image is about 1000x600. Fs is therefore a 1000x600 array of COMPLEX NUMBERS. Now my problem: Why is this so slow? If I set very few pixels to zero (e.g. kmin = 10, kmax = infinite) then the code runs quickly but if I have to set almost all pixels to 0.0 (e.g. kmin = 0, kmax = 10) it takes an incredible amount of time to complete.

All I do is set some array entries to zero (worst case less than 1,000,000 entries, maybe factor two because they are complex numbers). Why does this take up to minutes? :)

Comment: Some details on masking frequencies in the Fourier domain with matlab here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19879538/2777181

Answer (score 1):

Loops tend to be slow in Matlab (although that's improving in recent versions). You better [*vectorize*](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html), which means working with all values "at the same time", without loops. In this case you can do it using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and [linear / logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

```
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:w,1:h); %// creates all combinations
aux = sqrt((w/2-ii(:)).^2+(h/2-jj(:)).^2); %// compute norm
ind = (aux<kmin) | (aux>kmax); %// logical index
Fs(ind) = 0;
```

Comment: This is a good speedup for the OP's bad approach, but it is still a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the frequency from the index and seeing whether it falls into the passback, calculate the index corresponding to the cutoff frequency.

Once you have `n_cutoff_low` and `n_cutoff_high` calculated, setting all elements from `1:n_cutoff_low` and from `n_cutoff_high:end` to zero is easy and very fast.

Basically, you use fftshift to change your formula from

```
norm([w/2, h/2] - [i,j]) < kmin
```

to

```
norm([i,j]) < kmin
```

then square this to

```
i^2 + j^2 < kmin^2
```

which means

```
j^2 < kmin^2 - i^2
```

or

```
j_cutoff = floor(sqrt(kmin^2 - i^2));
Fs(i,-j_cutoff:j_cutoff) = 0;
```